# Linux OpenCV single so file for java

Tags: java, c++, linux, opencv

In `opencv-3.2` for windows, I get a `java` directory in `build` and there are two `opencv_java320.dll` files for 64-bit and 32-bit platforms and a `opencv-320.jar` file. Now in my java program, I can add them and use as expected.

Now to make it platform independent I wanted to do the same for Linux. But when I build them by `cmake` I get many `*.so` (e.g. `libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0`) files one of them is `opencv_java320.so`. How can I combine all the `*.so` files in one `opencv_java320.so` file like windows? Including the single `opencv_java320.so` does not work as it has the other `*.so` file dependencies.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't know about JAVA but if you want single `.so` file, you can build OpenCV with `BUILD_opencv_world` flag `ON`.